# How do I set a column value before inserting a row in Derby?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, derby

I'm trying to create a rough emulation of Oracle's ORA_ROWSCN in my Derby database.  I'm using Derby for unit testing so that a tester doesn't have to install Oracle Express or something like that.  So I have a statement that looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER 
my_table_bi NO CASCADE BEFORE 
INSERT ON my_table
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH STATEMENT MODE DB2SQL
NEW.ORA_ROWSCN = 1
```

I eventually want to make this more complex, but I'd like to start with making it even possible.  I get an error saying

> Syntax error: Encountered "NEW" at line 6, column 5

What am I missing?  Is this even possible?

Comment: I believe in general, it is, yes.  I believe it may be complaining about your name for new rows (`NEW`).  What happens if you rename the reference?  Also, you can only use the old/new _row_ references in 'row' triggers, otherwise [documentation says you need to use the table reference](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/rrefsqlj43125.html#rrefsqlj43125__sqlj54276)

Answer (score 0):

I use this to simulate a before insert, may be it will help you if it isn't too late.

```
DROP TRIGGER TRI_UPPER_FIRSTNAME_PERSONNES;
CREATE TRIGGER TRI_UPPER_FIRSTNAME_PERSONNES
AFTER INSERT ON PERSONNES
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE PERSONNES SET FIRSTNAME_PER = UPPER(NEW.FIRSTNAME_PER) WHERE NEW.SID_PER = SID_PER;
```